# Qual é o significado da palavra "cout" no C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, console, stream

Bem, é muito comum nas linguagens de programação haver palavras-chaves responsáveis para impressão da saída de dados.

Algumas são clássicas como `echo`, `print`, `printf` e `write`, etc.

Porém no `C/C++` temos o `cout`. Para mim, essa palavra não faz sentido  estar relacionado a impressão de dados(falo em uma tradução, por exemplo). Inclusive não achei uma tradução para essa palavra.

Por exemplo:

```
int main()
{
   cout << "Imprimindo o famoso HELLO WORLD!!!\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Qual é o significado da palavra `cout` afinal de contas?

Comment: `fopen()` também não é tão obvio assim hehe.

Comment: @rray `f` => file.

Comment: Em C o identificador `cout` não está reservado. Podes usá-lo para o que quiseres, por exemplo: `int cout = 42;` ou `struct cout { double cin; };` ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O `cout` não é uma palavra-chave da linguagem, é um objeto da biblioteca padrão e só pode ser usada através do *namespace* `std` e inclusão do *header* [`iostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream).

O significado seria [*console output*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout). Assim como `cin` seria *console input*. Ambos são *streams* de entrada e saída de dados pelo console.

Há quem considere que o "c" seria *character*. Pelo menos [é o que diz o criador da linguagem](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#cout). É esquisito mas faz algum sentido porque no fundo tudo que é enviado para o *stream* acaba sendo convertido para caracteres que vão para o console (ao contrário do que as pensam outros tipos não são impressos, só uma *string*, por isso todo tipo precisa poder ser convertido para *string* de alguma forma, mesmo sem criar um objeto novo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ah, tá explicado. E eu que achei que era porque não podia usar só `out` por talvez já ser reservado. :)

Comment: +1 simples e direto :D

Comment: Só uma pequena correção, `std::cout` não é uma função mas sim um objeto global.