# "void *reader(void *i)" Qual o equivalente em C++?

Tags: c, c++, c++11

Estou estudando Sistema Operacionais e tenho um exercício para fazer em C++ e estou com dúuvidas (o livro traz somente em Java), tenho que implementar um problema clássico de leitor e escritor usando semáforos e variáveis de controle... E estou estudando alguns códigos. A função abaixo foi escrita em C, porém quero escrevê-la em C++.

Como ficaria algo equivalente a isso? `void *reader(void *i)`. Nunca vi uma estrutura parecida com esta em C++, um ponteiro de `void` que tem como parâmetro um ponteiro `void` novamente ou algo assim.

```
void *reader(void *i)
{
    printf("\n-------------------------");
    printf("\n\n reader-%d is reading",i);

    sem_wait(&z);
    sem_wait(&rsem);
    sem_wait(&x);
    readcount++;
    if(readcount==1)
    sem_wait(&wsem);
    sem_post(&x);
    sem_post(&rsem);
    sem_post(&z);
    printf("\nupdated value : %d",sh_var);
    sem_wait(&x);
    readcount--;
    if(readcount==0)
    sem_post(&wsem);
    sem_post(&x);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praticamente todo código em C é um código em C++, então isto está em C++.

Não é um código [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/101). Em C++ provavelmente usaria um *template* no lugar de um `void *`, usaria um [*stream*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113302/101) no lugar do `printf()`, é possível que outras coisas seriam feitas diferentemente, dependendo do contexto, mas o código não deixa de ser C++.

Este código parece ter vários erros, aí é outro problema.

Comment: Resolvi o problema já, esqueci de marcar ali como resolvido, na vdd o codigo segue a logica certa para a solucao do problema... esta faltando somente resolver o problema de starvation para o algoritmo que fiz. desde ja agradeço.