# Como eu uso %d ou %c... na instrução cout?

Tags: c, c++, formatação, console

Estou estudando C e C++ e gostaria de entender como eu poderia transformar esse código escrito com `printf()` em `cout`, ou como usar as funções `%d` `%x` `%c`, etc. no `cout`.

```
int main()
{ 
printf("i make %d program \n" , 2)
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Bom, primeiramente, você precisa saber que o C++, ele é diferente, ele não é definido por modeladores de saida como %d, %x, ou coisas do tipo. Ao invés disso, você utiliza apenas a variável e os comandos modeladores.

Exemplo

int n = 5;
   cout<< n;

Você imprimira o valor 5...

Para imprimir em hexadecimal, cout << hex << n;

E assim por diante, existem diversos modeladores para C++, você pode aprende-los, no youtube, pesquisando apostila de c++, pdf's, cursos básicos..

Comment: ah entendi , o livro que estou estudando : como programar em c e c++ com visual studio , está me confundindo kk , ele pediu em um exercício para transcrever alguns números com porcentagem e float para c++ , mas ele só deu  a tabela do c , vou ter que pesquisar tudo dnv ;-;

Comment: Quer aprender c++ do básico até o avançado ? pesquise no youtube Marco Castro C++

Comment: o problema é esse kkk estou utilizando o livro como base a 1 mês se eu mudar agora vou embolar tudo kkk

Comment: Dependendo do livro, talvez seja melhor trocar, pelo que eu vi, o seu livro está embolando c com c++, e isso irá te confundir, pois são linguagens orientadas a tópicos totalmente diferentes.

Comment: victor , então você recomenda aprender pelo link do canal que me recomendou ? , esse livro explora bastante as duas , até agora estou entendendo muita coisa , é que estava com pressa pois preciso aprender as duas linguagens o mais rápido possível kk e ainda tenho que estudar java ,

Comment: Cara, se você está com pressa, você mal irá aprender o básico, e depois irá esqueçer muitas coisas importantes !! Quer aprender a programar de verdade em qualquer linguagem ? Cria uma conta em https://www.urionlinejudge.com é uma de programação com + de 1800 problemas desde iniciante até o básico. Cara, uma coisa, se você quer ser um programador "bom programador", faça uri.. sua lógica vai ser incrível.

Answer (score 6):

Você deve estudar [`stream` de io](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) e seus [manipuladores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). Exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto x = 65;
    cout << "i make " << x << " program\n";
    cout << "i make " << hex << x << " program " << endl;
    cout << "i make " << (char)x << " program " << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/faDRBg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fwwehcvp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/StreamGeneral.cpp).

O [`printf()` trabalha com convenções onde ele substitui uma parte do texto por algo que vem como parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204071/101), e o que é usado ali como *placeholder* determina o que fazer. C++ usa [fluxos de de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227339/101) que vão se enfileirando e produzem um resultado. Então ele vai montando cada elemento sendo que o primeiro item é quem recebe tudo o que vem depois. O [`cout` é a saída para o console](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113302/101).

Obviamente que sabendo o valor é melhor colocar tudo junto em uma *string* só. Só é legal usar isso quando não se sabe o que terá no *placeholder*, então neste caso vamos entender que esse `x` seria uma valor que vem externamente.

O segundo exemplo manda para um manipulador antes de mandar para a saída e o `hex` muda o formato de saída do número para hexadecimal, como o `%x` faria.

Também usei `\n` e `endl`, apensar de ambos terminarem uma linha tem diferenças entre eles (veja o *link* acima).

O terceiro exemplo tive que converter de número para `char` na mão. Bons compiladores de C configurados adequadamente exigem o mesmo. Note que o *stream*  não se importa com o tipo que vem. Se o tipo tiver um *stream* configurado ele saberá o que fazer. Todos os tipos básicos da linguagem possuem, e todos os tipos deveriam possuir algum operador `stream` configurado, é como se fosse um `ToString()` de outras linguagens.

Na documentação postada tem vários outros modificadores bem úteis para formatação dos dados. É possível até criar os seus com um pouco mais de conhecimento.

Comment: Entendi , você teria um site com lista das variáveis desse tipo? , hexadecimal , inteira etc...? preciso muito pois estou com uma atividade para transformar código c em c++.

Comment: Hexadecimal não é um tipo é uma representação e está no *link* que passei, um início dos tipos está em https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type. Esta é documentação "quase" oficial. Sugiro estudá-la de ponta a ponta. Você provavelmente está estudando por um livro ruim, ou então não está interpretando o texto corretamente. Tem muita arapuca por aí, principalmente coisa grátis. Na verdade talvez esteja com dificuldade por falta uma base de outras coisas da computação, pode ser que está usando algo pouco didático, o que é bem comum, em geral o material espera que você já tenha uma boa base.

Comment: principalmente em C++ que é uma das linguagens mais difíceis para aprender.

Comment: procurei muito livros que indicam o ensino pelo inicio , comparando o inicio do livro onde estou com vídeos do youtube estou achando super parecido mudando apenas o fato do livro ter exercícios , qual parte você me recomenda aprender antes? um tópico específico pois realmente aprender c e c++ junto é complicado.

Comment: C e C++ são linguagens muito diferentes e um dos grandes problemas é que quase todo mundo ensina como se fossem iguais, esse já é um erro bem básico que mostra que a pessoa que está ensinando não sabe do que está falando. Muito, mas muito comum mesmo. Tem que aprender fundamentos, entender como o computador funciona, o que está por trás de cada aspecto da linguagem, porque as coisas são como são, terminologias, conceitos computacionais. Todo mundo pula essa parte e por isso tem um monte de programador zumbi por aí.

Comment: É que estou precisando muito entender as duas o mais rápido possível , qual sua recomendação? , focar no c e ir devagar com c++ ou alguma outra?

Comment: Não sei, depende do que quer, eu iria só em uma, C é muito mais fácil. Conheço bem poucas pessoas que entendem bem das duas, eu não perderia tempo em tentar. Tem uns caras muito dedicados e experientes que não conseguem ser bons nas duas, só de ver o jeito que você escreve e faz as coisas eu acho que terá dificuldade com C que é bem mais simples. Vendo outros comentários, acho que você tá "loção" e não tem ideia de onde está se metendo.

Comment: na vida tudo é um desafio e ninguém nasce sabendo , vou começar por c mesmo   vou 'pular' a parte do livro que explora c++ e continuar em c , obrigado pelos comentários e os links , vai me servir muito!

Comment: Existe desafio e enfiar o pé na jaca

Comment: rsrs mil desistirão a sua direita , 10 mil a sua esquerda , mas você não vai desistir !!! :p

Comment: @VitorGonçalves provavelmente a idéia dos comments acima não é fazer você desistir, e sim fazer você "não insistir errado". O que vale na perseverança é o esforço de entender o certo e errado e ir melhorando e corrigindo o que faz. Não insista no erro, pq ai é perda de tempo. A partir do momento que diz "estou precisando muito entender as duas o mais rápido possível", das duas uma: Ou como o Maniero disse, está "enfiando o pé na jaca", ou então dê enfase para o "rápido POSSIVEL" que você mesmo disse, e desacelere um pouco fazendo os passos básicos, que aí vai valer a pena.

Comment: realmente exagerei , é que minha faculdade vai começar agora e estava uns 2 anos parado só trabalhando com montagem e manutenção , nunca aprendi nada sobre programação e o curso de tecnologia da informação pela grade vai ser necessário ter muito conhecimento nessa área , estou estudando direto pra tentar chegar e não ter muitas dificuldades.