# Está executando os comandos direto sem tempo de digitar as outras notas

Tags: c, c++, entrada-de-dados

Não está deixando digitar o resto, só de digitar o primeiro já vai para o último.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int n1,n2,pim,rn1,rn2,rpim,rfinal;
     rn1=n1*4;
     rn2=n2*4;
     rpim=pim*2;
     rfinal=(rn1+rn2+rpim)/10;
    printf("Entre com a Primeira Nota\n");
     scanf("&i",n1);
     printf("Entre com a Segunda Nota\n");
     scanf("&i",n2);
     printf("Entre com o Pim");
     scanf("&i",pim);
     printf("Nota Final e %i",rfinal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Esse código tem vários problemas e não faz muito sentido.

Primeiro que está usando C++ mas programando em C. Não deveria fazer isso mesmo que funcione. Então é [melhor usar *streams*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113302/101), já que até colocou o `include` dele.

Todos os cálculos estão sendo feitos antes dos dados entrados, e como as variáveis não forma inicializadas podem dar qualquer valor. Também poderia só declarar a variável quando ela é necessária.

Está passando as variáveis por valor e não por referência que é o correto no `scanf()` (apesar que nem deveria estar usando esta função). Tem um `&` que deve estar imaginando que tem que colocar no gabarito de formatação, não é aí que coloca. E [o ideal é uso do `%d`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152401/101), o `i` é para outra outra.

Minha sugestão é entender o que é cada recursos, cada caractere do código antes de tentar usar cada coisa. Jogar texto aleatoriamente não fará aprender.

Por último, o Dev C++ é um IDE considerado bem ruim de se usar.